# Dynamic WorkFlow emails won't sent, however static emails send issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-email, outgoing-email

WorkFlow emails will not send dynamically after an item is added to a custom list. Though the logs look clean and can send emails statically.

We're in the process of creating a issue tracking "system" and we decided to use SharePoint because its lightweight and can get the job done.

The functionality we would like to achieve is to have the user add an item to a custom list that summarizes there issue in a simple form.

Upon successful addition of the item to the list we would like an email to be sent to the Maintenance team to solve the issue. Once the Maintenance team solves the issue they will update the "ticket" and the update will send the user a response by kicking off another workflow similar to the first one that summarizes the solution.

In essence we have two workflows sending emails when a item is added and updated.

At first the WorkFlows wouldn't send they would kcik back an exchange server error. We fixed that and passed the right credentials to the SMTP server. We tested by sending messages statically from the server and it worked.

However, when an item was added the workflows would kick off but no email was sent.

We then checked the logs and it was kicking a Forms Based Administrator error so we patched that issue and tried again with no success. We then saw something else in the logs concerning a Visigo library so we added that.

Now the logs look clean however the emails still will not fire.

Any ideas I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010

Comment: Are you trying to send these emails to a distribution list? If so, that won't work.